# Facebook Page plugin shows only link but not the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

my facebook page plugin is just showing me a link and not the page.I tried adding http,https to js.src but nothing has worked.I also tried it locally as well as on the hosting server but gives me the same result .

```css
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/betasportsclub/?fref=ts" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/betasportsclub/?fref=ts" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/betasportsclub/?fref=ts">BETA Sports Club</a></blockquote></div>
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  
  
  </body>
```

Comment: did you check the browser console for errors/warnings? can you provide a test link?

Comment: @luschn http://getgrep.in/test.html..checkout

Comment: so...what exactly does not work? the page plugin shows up for me.

Comment: does it show the post and all the other stuff...

Comment: Hey works in chrome but doesn't open in mozilla..just found that out..plz check if it opens in mozilla...if it doesn't give some solution..

Comment: works fine in firefox too. looks like it´s a problem on your end. check the browser console.

Comment: Okk thanks I find the problem if it's on my end....